# Google Sheet: Return multiple columns based on their value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google SpreadSheet that is helping us review candidates' applications.

Each column in the sheet represent a parameter and every candidate receives a score for the parameters of the column of `Poor, Good, Excellent` as seen on the image:

[image]

I want to create two summary cells that provide all the parameters that a candidate were poor and excellent at.

Which formula should I use to output the column names of each Poor/Excellent score in each row?

So the result will be:
[image]

Added a spreadsheet for testing:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fPr5mpY74z3gr3c7PRrfk79oPTyV4aG8Qj9IEqXwDds/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fPr5mpY74z3gr3c7PRrfk79oPTyV4aG8Qj9IEqXwDds/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Access Denied on your shared sheet.

Comment: Not it should be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in cell B2:

```
=join( 
  ", ", 
  filter( 
    Review!$B$2:$U$2, 
    filter(Review!$B$3:$U, Review!$A$3:$A = $A2) 
    = 
    B$1 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: @AsafNevo seems that you made the sheet private after getting help.  This kind of defeats the purpose of this website as a resource for future users.  Could you please put the sample back to View-able?

Comment: That is correct, and i agree with your point, i will re add it